# Unable to find IN keyword in Robot Framework. How to use for loop without using IN keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, robotframework, selenium2library

I want to use for loop to iterate the element in a list. but i think the library is missing. when IN keyword is taken it gives error.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Acuvue inquiry

    @{index} =    BuiltIn.Create List    a    b
    FOR    ${item}    IN    @{index}
        BuiltIn.Log    ${item}
```

Error :

## Acuvue Inquiry

Acuvue inquiry                                                        | FAIL |
FOR loop contains no keywords.

Comment: the pythonic `in` is written in small letters - not capital ones. I don't see what the python tag has to do with your code as that seems not to be python. please fix your tags and/or code. you are also not using one bit of selenium in your code if I am not mistaken.

Comment: The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop in RobotFramework follows a very strict syntax - this is the "new" syntax, where the in-loop keywords don't start with `\`, but the loop body must be closed with an END:

```
FOR    ${item}    IN    @{index}
        BuiltIn.Log    ${item}
END
```